# What did the Jews hear at Sinai?

Tags: kabbalat-hatorah, hearing

I seem to recall that there is somewhat of a *machlokes Rishonim* over what exactly it was that the Jews heard at Sinai. Some say that all 10 commandments were heard, while others say that only the first two were heard, while still others say that nothing was heard by all the Jews at all. I was wondering if anyone could help find me sources for these things? I've been looking around (especially for the one that they collectively heard nothing), but have not been able to come up with anything.

Comment: Duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/39009/1713

Comment: I'm not familiar with anyone saying that they ONLY heard the first two commandments, only that those were directly from HASHEM and the rest were related by Moshe...

Comment: @Daniel Looks like it.

Comment: I hears that all 10 were heard at once from Hashem then the first two were repeated by Hashem and then moshe said the other eight.