# Flaws in the Kuzari Argument

Tags: faith-bitachon-emunah

I recently came across something that challenged my faith. I have believed in Judaism because of the Kuzari Argument. I thought it was a very good argument. But then I came across this article (http://www.talkreason.org/articles/kuzariflaws.cfm#lep). Most of the article I was able to refute because I realized that the person misunderstood the Kuzari Argument. But the part about the Irish history myth (click on leprechauns in contents) seems to be pretty convincing. Is there anybody who can refute this?

Comment: Probably better not to base your Judaism on just the Kuzari. Otherwise you'll forever be swinging back and forth as you analyze every detail ad absurdum

Comment: *I have believed in Judaism because of the Kuzari.* Do you mean because of the Kuzari (a  Twelfth Century book), or because of the Kuzari Argument (a modern formulation of a particular evidentiary point) that is loosely based on the Kuzari?

Comment: I'm vaguely reminded of the section in which Rihal talks about the beliefs of the Hindus. I'd have to look inside to see if there's actually a connection.

Comment: @Alex The Kuzari Argument

Comment: @DoubleAA So what should I base my Judaism on?

Comment: @Alex what part of the Kuzari is defined as "The Kuzari Argument"?

Comment: @Harel13 None. The Kuzari Argument is a modern formulation of a proof to the truth of Judaism (or more specifically, the revelation at Sinai) popularized by authors such as R. Dovid Gottlieb, R. Lawrence Keleman, kiruv seminars, etc. It is loosely based, and much expanded from, one statement in the Kuzari (the gist of which R. Saadia Gaon actually said earlier).

Comment: @Alex oh, that bit? Yeah, heard it in the past. Thanks.

Comment: this looks interesting (haven't read) https://kodeshpress.com/product/strauss-spinoza-sinai-orthodox-judaism-and-modern-questions-of-faith/

Answer (score 4):

The guy seems to misunderstand the Kuzari with regard to this point as well. Of course you can rewrite history and get people to believe all sorts of things took place in the history of their country when in fact those things never happened. Particularly when you are dealing with not particularly  educated population to begin with. Because someone reading revisionist history does not have the obvious question of "why don't I know about it?" The answer is simple "you weren't born yet, it never had any reason to came up and now you are being taught by the history  experts" Ditto when mythology  turns into something people believe. The people have no intrinsic  obvious reason not to believe it.

What you can't do is convince an entire country that either (1)they themselves saw something  which they didn't see but because they saw it they need to take on many, many practices and obligations and celebrate many commemorations of their seeing it or (2)their ancestors saw something and because  of what they saw they immediately     started  many, many practices and obligations and many  celebrations commemorating  their seeing it happen, when none of those things are actually  in practice. Because then you would never be able to get around the question of "why didn't I hear about this until now?". And if  a mythology claims to have  a practical outcome that clearly isn't the case it would perpetually  be recognized as mythology.

The Kuzari is discussing the latter situation. Belief in leprechauns is the former.

I've seen other variations of this question. They all involve a parallel situation where there was no obvious question of "if this  is true then why don't I  know about it  already?" The parallel events  are like Eliyohu on Har HaKarmel or the Mohn falling. They are also miraculous events believed to have been widely viewed but no  says that belief in those events proves the truth of Judaism.

Comment: How many people believe there were 1.5 million people at Trump's inaugural address? Let's not overestimate people's intelligence and or discount the strength of a charismatic leader to tell lies that slowly evolve out of anyone sane's wildest imagination. If anything the echo-chamber effect of politicized news sources was stronger 5000 years ago when all you had to compare to was your neighbor.

Comment: Is there in fact a widespread belief that there were 1.5 million people at Trump's inaugural address? Based on photos of the event is it  clearly untrue? Were the pictures the same but it was the press rather than Trump who saying it was 1.5 million people would it be a  clear case of fake news? Of more relevance would you be able to convince people today that Trump had a SECOND  inauguration with hundreds of thousands of people in attendance?

Comment: Yes to everything but the last one, and even the last one I'm not sure he couldn't have done if he'd wanted to. I certainly couldn't but he might be able to. The question isn't what I could do, but what Trump could do to a captive audience of idiots. Multiplied by many many chances over the generations; recall unlikely things happen often enough given enough chances.

Comment: You are just writing  subjective expressions of personal belief .

Comment: Ahh but isn't that all the argument ever is? How good are humans really at estimating how likely unlikely things are over many repetitions? That's why discussing if this is a binary logical proof or not is somewhat missing the point.

Comment: No. Everyone understands you can not  do what is explained in the second paragraph of my answer and that it has never  been done. Your beliefs about peoples  beliefs and strength of evidence of how many people attended Trumps first (and second...) inauguration are subjective opinions of yours . I will not respond to you further.

Comment: Claims like "everyone understands" rarely convince those that don't.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the point about “why didn’t I hear about this until now”? Let’s say it’s the first thing I tell kids who reaches the age of understanding. When could they conceivably have heard about it earlier if it was true?

Comment: @Schmerel The number of intelligent people who have studied history/religion/Kuzari and still don't think a revelation at Sinai occurred calls your "everyone understands you can not do what is explained in the second paragraph of [your] answer and that it has never been done" into doubt.

Comment: Alex: Don't get your question. Are you suggesting the possibility  of masses of people who never saw something  told it their children as the first thing when they reached the age of understating?  maicker72: I've seen many people who rejected the Kuzari. None of them claimed to believe it can be done bringing a comparable example.

Comment: @Schmerel I'm not up to that step yet. First I need to understand the premise. When would someone have been told about it, such that it is possible to ask "why wasn't I told previously?"

Comment: Anytime someone is told to start keeping  hundreds  of practices because of something that happened on a national scale that they never heard of they would question why they never heard about it.

Comment: What if they were told to keep one practice? And then their kid was told one practice should be two practices? (Alternatively: that Revelation was seen by only a few people and then few became dozens, dozens became hundreds, etc. ) That's the other big issue here. No one rejected R' Akiva for making up that there were hundreds of plagues instead of the 10 we all know from tradition. Trump uses the same tactic of changing the goalposts.

Comment: And what if...If you evidence to believe that a group had a history radically differently from what they believe we will discuss it. Otherwise there are no end to hypothetical questions about anything. Rav Akiva gave detail about the ten makkos. Not a rewriting. Yes Trumps supporters and opponents believe all sorts of nonsense lies about him based on what they are told . Even so neither group would ever claim he had a second inauguration or didn't have a first. Because there are limits to how obvious of a  lie people will believe. The inauguration is analogues to the Kuzari. Not propaganda

Comment: @Schmerel But my question was when should they have heard of it? I don’t see that you’ve addressed that.

Comment: @Schmerel What's the difference between a give detail and a rewriting? How many give details in a row equals a rewriting?

Comment: Eh never mind I don't feel like pulling out your hidden assumptions the hard way. You can quibble about any potential counterexample but they are still useful to expose the logical structure. The potential issues here are well documented in many places by people who have written it in a much more organized fashion. like https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35234/759

Comment: Alex. I don't understand your question. The Kuzari is saying (among other things) that the first generation  presented with something like the Torah would  question why they never heard of it before. What is your question?

Comment: @Schmerel Let’s say the first generation is my kid. Where should he have expected to hear it before hearing it from me?

Comment: So then you are suggesting the possibility  of a generation who falsely  told their children they saw events they did not see or claimed to have traditions from their parents they did not have. That is an outlandish proposal . How did anyone get the parents to do it?

Comment: For the tenth time Schmerel that's a false dichotomy. The claim is a generation of parents told their children they had a traditional that something happened, and those children told their children that they had a tradition that a few people saw God, and those children told their children that they had a tradition that a few hundred people saw God, etc. Parents adapt stories all the time. That's why nursery rhymes don't look exactly the same only 100 years later. That's why most Jews think they have a tradition that dreidel is from a game played against Greeks.

Comment: Honestly how many Jews today would think to protest if I told their kid the following lie "we have an old tradition the Maharal made a Golem that all the Jews of Prague saw at shul". Not many, and that's was made up less than ~6 generations ago. Most by now probably even assume it's true.

Comment: @Schmerel Maybe the parents made it up themselves.

Comment: Alex: Do parents normally lie to their children about such things? Even if you believe they do the conspiracy theory possibility of maybe a generation of parents (or fill in the blank for any other group)  made something up on a mass level could be used to cast doubt  on any and all historical facts. Do you normally accept such theories?

Comment: These type of "what if" questions need evidence to require an answer . Why do I know  about Christian pagan holiday  but not about Jews? Anyway no one was doing Mitzvas that explicitly  say they are to commemorate Yetzias Mitzrayim (about a third of all mitzvas are) because of a retroactively made  story.

Comment: @Schmerel Wikipedia says there are an estimated 10,000 religions in the world. If only one of them is true, that's a lot of people lying about religions. And I didn't say anything about a generation of parents. I said that I told my kid something. Maybe a few of my friends told their kids something too. No conspiracy theories on mass levels there. In any case, we certainly have examples of parents mass lying to their kids even in recent times, and it tends to work (at least until the kids become old/smart enough to figure out the truth).

Comment: How did all the parents get together and lie about the Tooth Fairy? Santa Claus? How babies are made? That Elijah drank the wine at the seder? Did a kid ever say "If the Tooth Fairy is real, how come I never heard about it before?"?

Comment: @Schmerel You are arguing against a straw man because according to the academics, first they accepted the laws and then they accepted the story of Sinai later

Comment: @Alex Are u saying u don't believe that Eliyahu HaNavi drinks the wine at the Seder?

Comment: @Champ Maybe he does, maybe he doesn’t. But if the cup has a hole in the bottom for wine to trickle out of, or the parent deliberately shakes the table or otherwise spills some out then I know the parent is lying.

Comment: First, as I said in my answer, the Kuzari couldn't be giving a philosophical proof in a text that comes out aganst them. You are turning his argument from tradition into a philosophical proof that our tradition is of a sort that cannot be falsified.

Comment: Second, here is one way a story like that can get started. In one generation, it's a story people tell their children at bedtime about how their nation began. No one takes its historical claims  seriously, but it's a nice symbolic story to keep alive by telling the kids. A few generations, it is told as "some believe". A few generations after that, over a century after the story was invented, it could easily be declared as fact. After all, everyone's grandparents HAD heard the story.

Comment: Third. none of that matters, because people believe what fits their experiences and satisfies what Viktor Frankl called Man's Search for Meaning. That includes which proofs we think are sound logic founded on obvious first principles and which we question. Philosophy has come a long way since Aristotle. The general consensus in the field since Kant or maybe a generation before has been that proofs of the kind the Rambam tried to construct simply do not exist. We believe in G-d for the same reason we believe the sky is blue -- that's the way the world looks to us personally.

Comment: As I said if you going to go with “what if” speculation of possible factors influencing events then you can question anything and join the fringe conspiracy theorists on everything. But since so many comments insist on using that logic let's compare apples to apples. Tell me which other large groups with clear historical records of their own do you believe or even suspect  really had radically different origins and WHY do you believe that?

Answer (score 4):

I think that the aspect of directly refuting the leprechauns has been properly dealt with by a previous answer; and I do believe it has been refuted.

My answer would like to address an equally important factor in answering your question IMHO. I think this is really important and integral to the OP. It is like the pot of gold at the end of the rainbow after you deal with the leprechauns standing in the way. It is that important.

René Descartes was a famous French philosopher (1596 - 1650), who (among other things of course) investigated questions of what would constitute "proof" of a matter?

For instance, Descartes asked how you know you are not really sleeping right now and everything you are experiencing was just a dream? He grappled with this in order to truthfully understand the concept of real 100% proof.

So for instance accordingly, "Cartesian" proof that there are no dragons would require you to have video footage of every part of the universe in front of you at once showing no dragons anywhere etc.

That's great for philosophy and it has its place. However, in real life, this will not get you very far.

For instance, maybe there is a chance that the bus driver is a secret terrorist or the medicine in your prescription was replaced with Jim Jones' koolaid in the middle of the night?

Do you stop riding buses or stop taking your medicine?

No, that would be silly. This is because life decisions on a daily basis do not require and should not entertain a need for Cartesian proof of anything, or you will never cross the street.

The Kuzari principle is a holy philosophy, but it has its limits in the realm of intellect, as does everything.

The great value of the Kuzari principle is that it A) Makes a lot of sense and B) is not really refuted.

Is it 100% proof? Has it no weaknesses? Maybe it does have a flaw, SO WHAT??

When choosing a religion and philosophy, one must choose a practical path which has been shown to be most likely true and much better than alternatives. The Kuzari principle grants that to Judaism on an intellectual level.

We absolutely do not need the Kuzari to refute every possible scenario in history or every oral tale. It is 99% bulletproof (or even 88% bulletproof would be fine) and it does its job.

That job is to grant a person the freedom, right, and confidence to go down the path of Judaism knowing that it is the most rational choice and option to investigate as a religion, revelation, and way of life.

The Kuzari does not have to be 100% irrefutable in every way. You just need to be allowed to be convinced enough that it holds a huge amount of intellectual honesty. Such cannot be said for any other religion on Earth. Thats good enough.

You never demand 100% from the bus driver, and you do not lock your medicine in a secret vault every night for fear of tampering. So why would you feel the need to demand that your initial religious guidance must deliver 100% irrefutable chances of accuracy?

The real challenge is no longer the question of "is Judaism the true path?" The question now is how to pull off getting yourself to include Judaism in every aspect of your life. How do you pray (Talk with your Creator?) How do you live a better life? That would be a much more important trick than refuting the leprechauns.

I hope I expressed this correctly. :)

Comment: A very nice and meaningful answer. I would say that the last percentage is perhaps the leap of faith that is required in faith (hence it being called a "leap of *faith*". I heard a rabbi once say about his faith something along these lines: He isn't 100% that Judaism is the truth, but since this is where he is in life, he thinks it's the best way to go.

Comment: @DavidKenner I think this is a very good answer! Thank you!

Comment: thanks people, i appreciate it. Much Success. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you speak of "The Kuzari Principle" you are talking about the majority of book I of the Kuzari the way it is usually presented in *kiruv* contexts or other inspirational programs. Something like this:

No one could invent a story that alleges all of the target’s audience’s ancestors experienced some miraculous or otherwise special event. It is implausible that a lie could be consistently retold by millions. And, the audience’s reaction would be one of disbelief, “Why does he know all about this event, and we never heard of it before from our grandparents?” Since Judaism uniquely makes claims of national miracles and national revelations, events with audiences of millions who are the ancestors of nearly all of the target audience (excepting *geirim*) this gives Judaism a unique claim to authenticity. The commonality of the story amongst so many and the acceptance of the story by their descendants is unique. (In contrast, Jesus’s alleged miracles were only said to be witnessed by at most the 500 attendees of the wedding at Cana, and the target audience isn’t primarily the descendants of those guests.)

However, I do not believe this is the Kuzari’s point. Before I get to what I believe Rabbi Yehudah haLevi really is saying in book 1, this argument is flawed for two reasons:

First, there are counterexamples, other cultures that had myths about their origins that they all believed. For example, the Theban origins myth. Central American myths about gods who appear and lead whole peoples. I didn't look into it, maybe the Irish myths you mention qualify too.

Second, and this may explain how the counterexamples emerged, the assumption is made that the claim is made out of the blue, in a single stroke. It doesn’t account for gradual acceptance of a story. Say something starts out as a myth about a subset of the people, and it’s known to be a bed-time story. The next generation it’s “some say”. Over several generations, it can become “official history” about everyone, with no one generation expressing the disbelief that is critical to this argument.

But the actual reason why I doubt that this is Rav Yehudah haLevi’s intent is because he had the king already approach a philosopher as well as a Christian Scholast, and the king already rejected philosophical proof as unconvincing. The Rabbi provides as a counterpoint to his statement (Kuzari I, par 13):

> The Rabbi: That which you describe is religion based on speculation and system, the research of thought, but open to many doubts. Now ask the philosophers, and you will find that they do not agree on one action or one principle, since some doctrines can be established by arguments, which are only partially satisfactory, and still much less capable of being proved.

In other words, the Rabbi’s basis for belief is not one based on “speculation and system”. It’s not philosophical proof. Reducing his words to an argument of the style described above defeats the whole point Rav Yehudah haLevi is trying to make! As he later writes (par 63), “There is an excuse for the Philosophers. Being Grecians, science and religion did not come to them as inheritances.”

The Kuzari can be seen as a response to Rav Saadia Gaon’s “Emunos veDei’os”, and on opposition to later such philosophical texts “The Guide for the Perplexed”, “The Ikkarim”. Rav Yehudah haLevi rejected the entire tendency of placing Jewish belief on Greek Philosophical underpinnings.

Instead, he says that Judaism is unquestionable for the Jew because it is our heritage.

What is being mistaken for the above proof is the Rabbi’s argument to the king, who didn’t yet accept this heritage as his own, and needs to assess that entire choice. But not the approach advocated for a Jew.

I see a kindred — but still very different — approach in existential thought.

One of my signature files, the only one that’s a self-quote, reads, “The mind is a wonderful organ for justifying decisions the heart already reached.” This echoes the King of the Kazar’s objection to the philosopher, that for any philosophical position justified by argument, there are conflicting opinions whose adherents claim equally valid arguments.

The Kiruv Movement is not founded on philosophical dispute, even if many who teach in that context may think so. The most effective kiruv tool is the experience of a Shabbos. People do not accept the proofs of G-d and the Divine origin of the Torah and *halakhah* and therefore keep Shabbos. Rather, they experience Shabbos, get first-hand experience of the power of *halakhah*, and based on that believe in the authenticity of the Torah and its own claims about its origin.

In addition to the experience of performing *mitzvos*, Torah study too has this defining characteristic. Torah has an elegance one finds in the most “beautiful” of mathematical proofs despite tackling concepts far less simply defined. A discussion of the laws of theft could explain a seemingly unrelated point in the laws of Shabbos with a single theory (*sevarah*) uniting both.

I should be clear that I’m not speaking of the emotional reaction of liking Shabbos. Rather the experience of Shabbos, the first-hand but internal to the mind qualia of Shabbos, that that reaction is based upon. The difference between a mathematician finding a proof to be beautiful and the actual features of the proof that cause that judgement. It is as real and as objective as the experience seeing a ball. And just as I unquestioningly accept that a ball is red if I see that it’s red. I similarly accept the reality of Shabbos.

To extend this metaphor: What if many of us see the ball as red, but others, perhaps even a far larger group, insist they see it and it’s blue? Would their claims shake my faith in my own group’s perception, or would I trust my own eyes? (Assuming they work in general.) Why would the claims of another faith community (even the community whose faith is agnosticism or atheism) shake my belief in Torah?

Torah is based on first-hand experience of Torah, not on its “principles of faith”. My belief in those principles is because they explain that which I experience, not the other way around.

Rabbi Prof. Shalom Carmy (Yeshiva University) posted something similar to Avodah (an email discussion group):

> People who throw around big words on these subjects always seem to take for granted things that I don’t.

> The people who keep insisting that it’s necessary to prove things about G-d, including His existence, seem to take it for granted that devising these proofs is identical with knowing G-d.

> Now if I know a human being personally the last thing I’d do, except as a purely intellectual exercise, is prove his or her existence.

R’ Gil Student posted the following quote from Louis Jacobs, We Have Reason to Believe, pp. 25-26, 28-30 on Hirhurim:

> Since Kant, these proofs [of God’s existence] have been heavily assailed…. Many theologians, nowadays, accept the validity of these refutations and admit that there can be no proof of God in the sense that there can be no proof of a mathematical formula… But they go on to remark that we can be convinced of a thing beyond of a shadow of a doubt by means other than that of mathematical proof. There is no such proof, for instance, of the existence of other human beings beside ourselves, yet we are convinced that they do exist… In other words a distinction must be drawn between proof and conviction — proof is one of the ways to conviction but there are other ways, too…

> Many have arrived at this conviction as the result of a personal experience which convinces them that God exists. These men would rule out of court the very discussion of whether God exists, for, they would say, if a man is truly in love he does not ask himself if he is in love. The experience of God’s Presence is sufficient…

> Other thinkers, again, hold that though each of the traditional proofs in itself is unconvincing, taken together they are convincing… Granted that the proofs carry no weight as evidence, they are indications and as such have the power of supplementing each other…

> What it all amounts to is this, that while the existence of God cannot be proved if we start from the beginning, none of us do, in fact, start from the beginning. We are presented with two alternative beliefs about the ultimate reality and we have to choose between them. According to one view God exists–it is He Who created us, Who fashioned our minds and implanted the moral sense within us so that we are capable of recognizing beauty, truth and goodness and fighting ugliness, falsehood and evil. In this view the difficulty is how to account for the existence of evil. According to the other view there is no God… In this view the difficulties are how mind came from matter, how life emerged where there was no life before, how the universe itself came into being, how the good is possible of realisation and how man came to strive for it–how man as a tiny part of the universe came to pass judgment on it?

So to answer your question, I cannot refute flaws in the Kuzari proof. I instead ask if you really do rely on this or any other philosophical argument as the foundation of your faith. And if you do -- should you?

Judaism neither stands on proof nor ought to be about proof. (In this approach. Obviously, R’ Saadia Gaon, the Rambam, et al disagreed.) Rather, it stands on our having a relationship with Hashem and His Torah.

Comment: Without responding to your vague references to other groups (yes I am familiar with those claims)  simple question for you. If you truly believe that there are groups who claim to have an unbroken tradition of a  mass revelation from God why do YOU assume it did not happen? It would be  from the most well documented and recorded events in all of history.

Comment: @Schmerel -- because I don't found my belief on what others claim. As the answer itself says, I believe because the experiences of learning Torah, keeping Shabbos and numerous other mitzvos are compelling reason to believe I am experiencing something real.

Comment: You aren't answering the question. If you truly believe that there are groups who claim to have an unbroken tradition of a mass revelation from God why do YOU assume it did not happen? If you believe those groups exist to begin then you certainly are basing your (sociological) beliefs on what others told you and claimed. Why do you believe those who told you those groups exist but not those groups themselves ?

Comment: Is this from a different answer of yours? Seems familiar

Comment: I think he's saying a group of people claiming an unbroken tradition is a flawed proof as there are alternative explanations for its origin. That's why he doesn't believe it. @Schmerel

Comment: He certainly isn't giving an alternate explanation for their belief. Not believing them would be akin to not believing any other widely known and documented historical event for no reason. Having researched those claims about other groups  I don't accuse    those groups of knowingly lying themselves but those who present their belief as alternate group  claim of  an unbroken tradition of a mass revelation from God are bending the truth.

Comment: @Schmerel "He certainly isn't giving an alternate explanation for their belief." He certainly is. He literally wrote "this may explain how the counterexamples emerged..."  Read the post.

Comment: "this may explain..." and it also may not. If there is a large group claiming their origins are from a mass revelation from God and they have been following what he told them to do then ever since then their claim is from the most well documented events in all of history. Yes they may be lying. But they also may be saying the truth. No open minded truth seeker would just brush off their claim with no counterevidence because it is POSSIBLE  they are lying. This is completely   independent of the Kuzari. Such a group would call ALL  belief systems into question

Comment: @Schmerel as I said in my post, in real life no one questions their own experiences because there are people who say otherwise. You are expecting some kind of epistemological certainty of proof that neither exists nor what we even expect in any other sphere of life.